# Algorithm to slice into square matrix a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

i'm searching for a algorithm that take a matrix (in fact, a double entry array) and return an array of matrix that:
is square (WIDTH = HEIGHT)
all of the element in the matrix has the same value.
I don't know if that is clear, so imagine that you have a image made of pixels that is red, blue or green and i want to get an array that contained the least possible squares. Like the pictures shows

***EDIT:***

**Ok, maybe it's not clear: I've a grid of element that can have some values like that:**

0011121

0111122

2211122

0010221

0012221

That was my **input**, and i want in **output** somethings like that:

|0|0|111|2|1|

|0|1|111|22|

|2|2|111|22|

|00|1|0|22|1|

|00|1|2|22|1|

*When each |X| is an array that is a piece of the input array.*
**My goal is to minimize the number of output array**

Comment: Why the first rows has |0|0| two array and fourth row |00| one array ? I thought you were grouping similar characters.

Comment: Update is fine (same as picture) and an option is to use the hints described, You need an proper algorithm for grouping (output). Here is a little bit of work on boundaries, because squares made gaps ... (one square, do gaps and gaps should be checked also for possible inner squares ...)

Comment: @SyedAfzal, the first rows is outputing as 2 array [0],[0] because is a 1 by 1 square (it's the biggest square possible here). The fourth row is outputing (with the fifth one) as 1 big array [[0,0][0, 0]] because here, the biggest square possible is a 2 by 2 square.

Comment: @TraianGEICU Thanks for your answers, and your hints. Yes gaps is a "problem" in this algorithm. Don't you know a "grouping" algorithm that can solve my problem ? (for pathfinding we have A*, ...), but is there a existing algorithm that solve that ?

Comment: no idea if any standard algorithm but it's sound more like compression. Encounter 30 years ago something similar but with inputs as array with consecutive occurrences .... any way maybe further researches for similarities is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

This problem does not seem to have an efficient solution.

Consider a subset of instances of your problem defined as follows:

- There are only 2 values of matrix elements, say `0` and `1`.
- Consider only matrix elements with value `0`.
- Identify each matrix element `m_ij` with a unit square in a rectangular 2D grid whose lower left corner has the coordinates `(i, n-j)`.
- The set of unit squares `SU` chosen this way must be 'connected' and must not have 'holes'; formally, for each pair of units squares `(m_ij, m_kl) \in SU^2: (i, j) != (k, l)` there is a sequence `<m_ij = m_i(0)j(0), m_i(1)j(1), ..., m_i(q)j(q) = m_kl>` of `q+1` unit squares such that `(|i(r)-i(r+1)| = 1 _and_ j(r)=j(r+1)) _or_ (i(r)=i(r+1) _and_ |j(r)-j(r+1)| = 1 ); r=0...q` (unit squares adjacent in the sequence share one side), and the set `SUALL` of all unit squares with lower left corner coordinates from the integers minus `SU` is also 'connected'.

Slicing matrices that admit for this construction into a minimal number of square submatrices is equivalent to tiling the smallest orthogonal polygon enclosing `SU` ( which is the union of all elements of `SU` ) into the minimum number of squares.

[This SE.CS post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16661/tiling-an-orthogonal-polygon-with-squares) gives the references (and one proof) that show that this problem is NP-complete for integer side lengths of the squares of the tiling set.

Note that according to the same post, a tiling into rectangles runs in polynomial time.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints may be useful.

 For representation of reduced matrix, maybe a vector is better because it's needed to be stored (start_x,start_y,value ... not sure if another matrix very useful).

Step 1: loop on x for n occurrences (start with y=0)

Step 2: loop on y for/untill n occurrences. Most of cases here will be m lees then n.
(case m greater then n excluded since cannot do a square) Fine, just keep the min value[m]

Step 3: mark on vector (start_x,start_y, value)

 Repeat Step 1-3 from x=m until end x

Step 4: End x, adjust y starting from most left_x found(m-in vector, reiterate vector).
...

keep going till end matrix.

Need to be very careful of how boundary are made(squares) in order to include in result full cover of initial matrix.

 Reformulate full-initial matrix can be recomposed exactly from result vector.

(need to find gaps and place it on vector derived from step_4) 

 Note ! This is not a full solution, maybe it's how to start and figure out on each steps what is to be adjusted.